# MySQL query to calculate latest average prices using data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am working on a PHP and MySQL based system to organise products and expenses for a restaurant.

I have data organised in to four tables.

Items table

```
id | name
1  | Beer
2  | Vodka
```

Products table

```
id | item_id | name
1  |    1    | Budweiser
2  |    1    | Sam Adams
3  |    2    | Smirnoff
4  |    2    | Grey Goose
```

Supplier table

```
id | name
1  | Supplier 1
2  | Supplier 2
```

Expenses table

```
id | product_id | cost | quantity | supplier | date
1  |     1      | 2.99 |     1    |     1    |  2017-09-05
2  |     1      | 3.00 |     2    |     2    |  2017-09-10
3  |     1      | 2.50 |     1    |     1    |  2017-09-20
4  |     1      | 3.98 |     2    |     1    |  2017-09-22
5  |     1      | 4.00 |     1    |     2    |  2017-09-25
6  |     1      | 8.00 |     2    |     2    |  2017-09-27
```

I would like to write a MYSQL Query that can figure out the cheapest supplier of a specific product based on the average cost per item (cost/quantity) of the latest 3 entires in the expenses table (based on date).

Here's what I want to compute:

Supplier 1 last 3 entries - costs per unit of: 2.99, 2.50 and 1.99. Average = 2.49

Supplier 2 last 3 entries - costs per unit of: 1.50, 4.00 and 4.00. Average = 3.16

So the SQL should return that Supplier 1 is the cheapest option for Product 1 (Budweiser).

So far I have attempted this, but I am a bit lost and confused:

```
select * from products 
INNER JOIN expenses
ON products.id = expenses.product
AND products.item = '1'
ORDER BY (expenses.cost/expenses.quantity)
LIMIT 3;
```

The output of this query is which is a long way from what I'm trying to figure out :(:

```
id | item_id |  name   | id | product_id | cost | quantity | supplier | date
1  |    1    |Budweiser| 2  |     1      | 3.00 |    2     |    2     | 2017-09-10
1  |    1    |Budweiser| 4  |     1      | 3.98 |    2     |    1     | 2017-09-22
1  |    1    |Budweiser| 3  |     1      | 2.50 |    1     |    1     | 2017-09-20
```

The output I am looking for based on the sample data would be:

```
cheapest_supplier
        1
```

Comment: May we see an attempt at this work? Your first thing looks like it would be a joine between `Supplier` and `Expenses`, with an `ORDER BY`, and a `LIMIT 3`. You can do the average by running a second similar query, but using an average function (it'll be in the manual).

Comment: Thanks, @halfer This is as far as I've got.                                     
                   code`select * from products
INNER JOIN expenses ON products.id = expenses.product
AND products.item = '1'
ORDER BY (expenses.cost/expenses.quantity)
LIMIT 3;`

Comment: All the expense ids are 1. Why?

Comment: @Strawberry that is just sample data and a mistake when typing it up. I will edit it.

Comment: Seeing as it's a unit cost, I'm a little bit confused by the inclusion of quantity in the calculation. But maybe this is why I'm not an accountant!

Comment: @Strawberry The tables are used for other things in addition. The inclusion of quantity is simply to make input easier when looking at a receipt and putting the data into the DB. For example 2 Budweisers cost $3.98 - there is no need for the inputter to calculate the unit cost. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Unless it really has to be this way, it is normal in accounting and cashflow systems to store the unit cost of something (1 Budweiser) and then to have a quantity. "Cost" is expected to be 1 of something, but it seems to be reversed here - is there is a specific reason for that?

Comment: Would you clarify, by way of another edit, what output you would like? You can do `expenses.cost/expenses.quantity` for the average for one row, and then `AVG` for the dataset on top, as the answer below shows. (Aside for general knowledge: we really like edits to improve questions even after answers have been obtained, so that future readers can benefit from the clearest possible question).

Comment: @halfer I am justing looking to output the id of the cheapest supplier based on the average cost per item based on the last 3 expense records based on date.

Comment: "I am justing looking to output the id of the cheapest supplier based on the average cost per item based on the last 3 expense records based on date" @Dingo Bruce check mine answer should actually do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to write a MYSQL Query that can figure out the cheapest supplier of a specific product based on the average cost per
>   item (cost/quantity) of the latest 3 entires in the expenses table
>   (based on date).

A option would be a query that works with user variables to generate a ranking based on date.
And only select the three last dates.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (
   SELECT 
   * 
   , CASE 
       WHEN @supplier = supplier
       THEN @rank := @rank + 1 
       ELSE @rank := 1
     END 
      AS rank
   , @supplier := supplier 
   FROM 
     Expenses 
   CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
       @supplier := NULL
     , @rank := 0
    ) 
    AS
      init_user_params  
   WHERE
      product_id = 1       
   ORDER BY
      supplier ASC 
    , DATE DESC   
)
 AS Expenses_ranked 
WHERE
  Expenses_ranked.rank <= 3
```

**Result**

```
    id  product_id  cost    quantity  supplier  date        @supplier := NULL  @rank := 0    rank  @supplier := supplier  
------  ----------  ------  --------  --------  ----------  -----------------  ----------  ------  -----------------------
     4           1  3.98           2         1  2017-09-22  (NULL)                      0       1                        1
     3           1  2.50           1         1  2017-09-20  (NULL)                      0       2                        1
     1           1  2.99           1         1  2017-09-05  (NULL)                      0       3                        1
     6           1  8.00           2         2  2017-09-27  (NULL)                      0       1                        2
     5           1  4.00           1         2  2017-09-25  (NULL)                      0       2                        2
     2           1  3.00           2         2  2017-09-10  (NULL)                      0       3                        2
```

Using that results to generate a avg list per supplier.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   Expenses_ranked.supplier 
 , AVG(Expenses_ranked.cost / Expenses_ranked.quantity) AS AVG
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
   * 
   , CASE 
       WHEN @supplier = supplier
       THEN @rank := @rank + 1 
       ELSE @rank := 1
     END 
      AS rank
   , @supplier := supplier 
   FROM 
     Expenses 
   CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
       @supplier := NULL
     , @rank := 0
    ) 
    AS
      init_user_params  
   WHERE
      product_id = 1       
   ORDER BY
      supplier ASC 
    , DATE DESC   
)
 AS Expenses_ranked 
WHERE
  Expenses_ranked.rank <= 3
GROUP BY
  Expenses_ranked.supplier
```

**Result**

```
supplier  avg           
--------  --------------
       1  2.4933333333  
       2  3.1666666667
```

Now we can use a simple `ORDER BY [] ASC LIMIT 1` to get the cheapest supplier

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 Expenses_ranked_avg.supplier AS cheapest_supplier
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
     Expenses_ranked.supplier 
   , AVG(Expenses_ranked.cost / Expenses_ranked.quantity) AS AVG
  FROM ( 

    SELECT 
     * 
     , CASE 
         WHEN @supplier = supplier
         THEN @rank := @rank + 1 
         ELSE @rank := 1
       END 
      AS rank
   , @supplier := supplier 
   FROM 
     Expenses 
   CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
       @supplier := NULL
     , @rank := 0
    ) 
    AS
      init_user_params  
   WHERE
      product_id = 1       
   ORDER BY
      supplier ASC 
    , DATE DESC   
    )
      AS
        Expenses_ranked 
    WHERE
      Expenses_ranked.rank <= 3
    GROUP BY
      Expenses_ranked.supplier 
)
  AS Expenses_ranked_avg 
ORDER BY 
 Expenses_ranked_avg.avg ASC
LIMIT 1
```

**Result**

```
cheapest_supplier  
-------------------
                  1
```

**More optimal queries.**

What also is possible to declare the user variables within the where statement. 
Making it directly possible to filter out the ranking.

**Query**

```
  SELECT 
   *
  FROM
   Expenses 
  WHERE
   (
     CASE 
       WHEN @supplier = supplier
       THEN @rank := @rank + 1 
       ELSE @rank := 1
     END  
   ) 
 AND
   (@supplier := supplier )
 AND  
   @rank <= 3  
 AND  
   product_id = 1
ORDER BY 
   supplier ASC
 , DATE ASC
```

**Result**

```
    id  product_id  cost    quantity  supplier  date        
------  ----------  ------  --------  --------  ------------
     1           1  2.99           1         1  2017-09-05  
     3           1  2.50           1         1  2017-09-20  
     4           1  3.98           2         1  2017-09-22  
     2           1  3.00           2         2  2017-09-10  
     5           1  4.00           1         2  2017-09-25  
     6           1  8.00           2         2  2017-09-27
```

Now it's easy the use this result set to find the cheapest supplier.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   Expenses_ranked.supplier AS cheapest_supplier
FROM (  

  SELECT 
   *
  FROM
   Expenses 
  WHERE
   (
     CASE 
       WHEN @supplier = supplier
       THEN @rank := @rank + 1 
       ELSE @rank := 1
     END  
   ) IS NOT NULL 
 AND
   (@supplier := supplier ) IS NOT NULL
 AND  
   @rank <= 3  
 AND  
   product_id = 1
ORDER BY 
   supplier ASC
 , DATE ASC  
)
 AS Expenses_ranked 
GROUP BY
  Expenses_ranked.supplier
ORDER BY 
  AVG(Expenses_ranked.cost / Expenses_ranked.quantity) ASC
LIMIT 1
```

**Result**

```
cheapest_supplier  
-------------------
                  1
```

Comment: Thank you, this is producing exactly the result I was looking for. Now I just need to try and get my head around the code so I can learn from it!

Comment: @Dingo Bruce no problem that's why i broke down the query in multiple parts so is easier to understand what iam doing. The hardest part i think is the ranking where user variables are been used

Comment: Haven't seen you post before Raymond, but this is a great answer. Nice work!

Comment: @halfer thanks.. You didn't catch mine posts before.. We blame that on the difference in timezones

Answer (score 1):

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.product_id
     , x.supplier_id
     , x.date
     , ROUND(AVG(y.cost/y.quantity),2) total_cost
  FROM expenses x 
  JOIN expenses y 
    ON y.product_id = x.product_id 
   AND y.supplier_id = x.supplier_id
   AND y.date <= x.date 
 GROUP 
    BY product_id
     , supplier_id
     , date 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

Comment: Given the clarification, I guess this does not need the `GROUP BY`, but it can just be ordered by `y.cost/y.quantity ASC`, with a `LIMIT 1`, so the cheapest one is on top?

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry  in this query how do I specify which product_id to perform the query for? This needs to be part of a while loop so looking to insert a variable.

Comment: @halfer Is that right. My understanding remains that the calculation was to be based on the last 3 prices provided by each supplier.

Comment: @DingoBruce Some things you have to figure out for yourself ;-)

Comment: Strawberry: well, I will let @Dingo confirm, as he/she will have the best idea! I thought that the expected result of `cheapest_supplier=1` indicated that the average should be taken of each row individually, rather than of all rows. I initially took your view, but Dingo's last edit changed my mind a bit `:)`.