# How to determine start/end time for events from status logs stored every 2 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

MariaDB version: **version: 10.0.38-MariaDB-0+deb8u1**

I have a table where every 2 minutes is reported  the status for a device (ON/OFF) with it's timestamp in unix time.

```
select * from devices_stats 
where device_id = 'LivingLight' 
  AND timestamp BETWEEN 1570080242 AND 1570084922;

+-------+-------------+--------+------------+-------------+
| id    | device_id   | status | timestamp  | device_iddr |
+-------+-------------+--------+------------+-------------+
| 16416 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570080242 |           1 |
| 16427 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570080363 |           1 |
| 16438 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570080483 |           1 |
| 16449 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570080602 |           1 |
| 16460 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570080723 |           1 |
| 16471 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570080842 |           1 |
| 16482 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570080963 |           1 |
| 16493 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570081083 |           1 |
| 16504 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570081203 |           1 |
| 16515 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570081323 |           1 |
| 16526 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570081443 |           1 |
| 16537 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570081563 |           1 |
| 16548 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570081682 |           1 |
| 16559 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570081803 |           1 |
| 16570 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570081922 |           1 |
| 16581 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570082042 |           1 |
| 16592 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570082163 |           1 |
| 16603 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570082283 |           1 |
| 16614 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570082402 |           1 |
| 16625 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570082523 |           1 |
| 16636 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570082643 |           1 |
| 16647 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570082762 |           1 |
| 16658 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570082882 |           1 |
| 16669 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570083003 |           1 |
| 16680 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570083123 |           1 |
| 16691 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570083242 |           1 |
| 16702 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570083363 |           1 |
| 16713 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570083483 |           1 |
| 16724 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570083603 |           1 |
| 16735 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570083722 |           1 |
| 16746 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570083843 |           1 |
| 16757 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570083963 |           1 |
| 16768 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570084083 |           1 |
| 16779 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570084202 |           1 |
| 16790 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570084323 |           1 |
| 16801 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570084442 |           1 |
| 16812 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570084563 |           1 |
| 16823 | LivingLight | ON     | 1570084683 |           1 |
| 16834 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570084803 |           1 |
| 16845 | LivingLight | OFF    | 1570084922 |           1 |
+-------+-------------+--------+------------+-------------+
```

I would like to retrieve a list of "ON" events with start and end time.

considering the example above i want to have an output like this:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+
| device_id   | start      | stop       | 
+-------------+------------+------------+
| LivingLight | 1570080963 | 1570082882 |
| LivingLight | 1570084563 | 1570084683 |
```

Could you please help me to create the query?

Comment: What is your MySQL version ? Run `SELECT Version();` query and edit the question to add the details of the version.

Comment: here is my version:
10.0.38-MariaDB-0+deb8u1

Comment: to bad that means no windowing, if possible consider upgrading to a more modern version makes the query much more easy..

Comment: Should only those 2 rows be returned for that sample data?

Comment: @RaymondNijland even with Windowing, it is not a straight forward application of `LEAD()`.

Comment: *" even with Windowing, it is not a straight forward application of LEAD()"* indeed @MadhurBhaiya this feels like a data island problem

Comment: @jarlh yest those 2 rows are the optupt for the sample data

Comment: Upgrade to at least 10.2 so you can use `LEAD()` or `LAG()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach using user-defined variables. It is noteworthy that even Windowing functions cannot be used in a straightforward manner in this problem. Nevertheless, your version is old, and don't support them either. Following solution is generic, and handle scenario if you dont use `WHERE` condition on the `device_id` and want multiple `device_id` in the result-set.

General idea here is that we compute an "island number" (denoted as `chng` in the query) for successive rows (based on timestamp) having same `device_id` and `status` value (either ON or OFF). Eventually, we can filter out only those island which are having `ON` status, and then do aggregation to get `MIN()` (start timestamp), and `MAX()` (stop timestamp).

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE device_stats
    (`id` int, `device_id` varchar(11), `status` varchar(3), `timestamp` int, `device_iddr` int)
;

INSERT INTO device_stats
    (`id`, `device_id`, `status`, `timestamp`, `device_iddr`)
VALUES
    (16416, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570080242, 1),
    (16427, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570080363, 1),
    (16438, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570080483, 1),
    (16449, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570080602, 1),
    (16460, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570080723, 1),
    (16471, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570080842, 1),
    (16482, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570080963, 1),
    (16493, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570081083, 1),
    (16504, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570081203, 1),
    (16515, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570081323, 1),
    (16526, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570081443, 1),
    (16537, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570081563, 1),
    (16548, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570081682, 1),
    (16559, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570081803, 1),
    (16570, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570081922, 1),
    (16581, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570082042, 1),
    (16592, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570082163, 1),
    (16603, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570082283, 1),
    (16614, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570082402, 1),
    (16625, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570082523, 1),
    (16636, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570082643, 1),
    (16647, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570082762, 1),
    (16658, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570082882, 1),
    (16669, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570083003, 1),
    (16680, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570083123, 1),
    (16691, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570083242, 1),
    (16702, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570083363, 1),
    (16713, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570083483, 1),
    (16724, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570083603, 1),
    (16735, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570083722, 1),
    (16746, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570083843, 1),
    (16757, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570083963, 1),
    (16768, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570084083, 1),
    (16779, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570084202, 1),
    (16790, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570084323, 1),
    (16801, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570084442, 1),
    (16812, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570084563, 1),
    (16823, 'LivingLight', 'ON', 1570084683, 1),
    (16834, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570084803, 1),
    (16845, 'LivingLight', 'OFF', 1570084922, 1)
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
  device_id, MIN(timestamp) AS start, MAX(timestamp) AS stop 
FROM 
(
SELECT
  @c := IF(@s <> status OR @d <> device_id , @c+1, @c) AS chng, 
  @s := status AS status, 
  @d := device_id AS device_id, 
  timestamp
FROM 
(
  SELECT device_id, status, timestamp
  FROM device_stats 
  WHERE device_id = 'LivingLight' 
    AND timestamp BETWEEN 1570080242 AND 1570084922 
  ORDER BY device_id, timestamp
) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s := '', 
                   @d := '',
                   @c := 0) vars 
) t2 
WHERE t2.status = 'ON' 
GROUP BY device_id, chng;

| device_id   | start      | stop       |
| ----------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| LivingLight | 1570080963 | 1570082882 |
| LivingLight | 1570084563 | 1570084683 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6ETV2NQenkv3psrNuYn9vE/0)

Comment: you can possibly optimize this query into having one less nested subquery..  if you move the [MySQL user variable init (post of mine)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46515063/2548147) to the WHERE clause ... But it can be tricky but i can be a nice trick :-)

Comment: @RaymondNijland Actually, check this: https://mysqlserverteam.com/row-numbering-ranking-how-to-use-less-user-variables-in-mysql-queries/ 

Due to ORDER BY optimization triggering in (at some times), I prefer to explicity sort the data first in a subquery, and then in outer query do all the computations.

Comment: @RaymondNijland nevermind; I got your point. After looking at the third query in that answer.

Comment: no problem, i understood your argument as WHERE is always executed before ORDER BY it should always works correctly .. But using a extra subquery like you did is more easy to get right..