# MySQL multiple datetime intervals based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select all the date time intervals based on columns *driver* and *status*
Using the group by I can only get one interval per driver
There is a way to get all the intervals based on this two columns?
The important here are the periods when the driver has the status 1, considering a 'break' when the status is 0
What I expect to achive:

```
foo | '2019-10-01 00:00:00' | 1
foo | '2019-10-01 00:16:40' | 0
foo | '2019-10-01 00:16:50' | 1
foo | '2019-10-01 00:33:20' | 0
foo | '2019-10-01 00:33:20' | 1
foo | '2019-10-01 00:50:00' | 0
foo | '2019-10-01 00:50:10' | 1
foo | '2019-10-01 01:06:40' | 0
bar | '2019-10-01 00:15:00' | 1
bar | '2019-10-01 00:31:40' | 0
bar | '2019-10-01 00:31:50' | 1
bar | '2019-10-01 00:48:20' | 0
bar | '2019-10-01 00:48:30' | 1
bar | '2019-10-01 01:05:00' | 0
bar | '2019-10-01 01:05:10' | 1
bar | '2019-10-01 01:21:40' | 0
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6mom9szF2zNKXFk4HGHXbp/3

Thanks in advance

*************** Edit *****************
The group by is only an example of what I'm trying to get as a result, it will never give me what I want because I'm grouping only the columns driver and status. It only return one 'range' (from 1 to 0) per driver, I need all ranges
Based on the raw data of the fiddle, using the driver 'foo', here is an example:

```
'foo', '2019-10-01 00:00:00', '1'-|
'foo', '2019-10-01 00:00:10', '1' |
...                               |  range 1 where the driver foo has status 1
'foo', '2019-10-01 00:16:30', '1' |
'foo', '2019-10-01 00:16:40', '0'-|

'foo', '2019-10-01 00:16:50', '1'-|
'foo', '2019-10-01 00:17:00', '1' |
...                               |  range 2 where the driver foo has status 1
'foo', '2019-10-01 00:33:10', '1' |
'foo', '2019-10-01 00:33:20', '0'-|

'foo', '2019-10-01 00:33:30', '1'-|
'foo', '2019-10-01 00:33:40', '1' |
...                               |  range 3 where the driver foo has status 1
'foo', '2019-10-01 00:49:50', '1' |
'foo', '2019-10-01 00:50:00', '0'-|


'foo', '2019-10-01 00:50:10', '1'-|
'foo', '2019-10-01 00:50:20', '1' |
...                               |  range 4 where the driver foo has status 1
'foo', '2019-10-01 01:06:30', '1' |
'foo', '2019-10-01 01:06:40', '0'-|
```

As a result I expect this:

```
foo | '2019-10-01 00:00:00' | 1
foo | '2019-10-01 00:16:40' | 0
foo | '2019-10-01 00:16:50' | 1
foo | '2019-10-01 00:33:20' | 0
foo | '2019-10-01 00:33:20' | 1
foo | '2019-10-01 00:50:00' | 0
foo | '2019-10-01 00:50:10' | 1
foo | '2019-10-01 01:06:40' | 0
```

I don't know if there is a way to get this result with a simple query, accept any suggestion

Comment: Also about time learning that `SELECT * .. GROUP BY ..` is generally invalid sql to write -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6mom9szF2zNKXFk4HGHXbp/3 .. This [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) explains how MySQL should have processed GROUP BY from the start..

Comment: This is not a complete question.  Please rephrase it by showing us clear input data, the expected output, along with a description of the logic along with any query you have already tried.

Comment: like @TimBiegeleisen said and to add to it ... The question needs be more clearly as the expected results does not match up with the example fiddle..   No idea what you mean i first was thinking the expected is showing missing records as 0 like a range table but 2019-10-01 00:16:50 is not found the source data..

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). Note: The data set provided above is not MINIMAL

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try to be more clear

Comment: You logic is not clear to me, because in the dbfiddle examle isn't any status 0. so i defined1) if oldstatus = 1 and new status = 1 get timedifference 2) if oldstatus is 1 and new status is 0 , also get the difference. 3) If oldstatus is 0 and the new status is 1 , the difference is 0 because it is a break . you can see what  it lokks like at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=06434751818a93ea02cf1c58fd8f7be0

Comment: @nbk sorry if it's not clear enough, I've updated the question

Comment: @gdurga what is your MySQL version ? Run `SELECT Version();` and report the result of this please.

Comment: And, why don't you have the very first row : `('foo', '2019-10-01 00:00:00', '1')` in the result-set ?

Comment: Your expected output has incosistencies; anway if I understand correctly, it is a data-island problem. You will have to use a slight variation of the technique in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217219/how-to-determine-start-end-time-for-events-from-status-logs-stored-every-2-minut/58217736#58217736  Give it a try! if stuck, let us know.

Comment: You are completely right @MadhurBhaiya, the first row of my expected result should be 'foo', '2019-10-01 00:00:00', '1'. The data-island approach look very promising, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: You're all very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i think i have it.

The Query is

```
   SELECT
   Min( driver) driver ,

   min(date_hour) date_hour,
   MIN(status) status
   FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        driver,
        status,
        date_hour,
        range_1
      FROM
        (SELECT 
           a.driver,
           a.date_hour, 
           a.status,
           if(a.driver = @olddriver, 
                IF (a.status = 1,IF(@oldstatus= 1
                ,@range,@range:=@range+1),IF(@oldstatus= 0,@range,@range:=@range+1))
             ,@range:=@range+1) range_1,
                @olddriver := driver,
                @oldstatus := status
         From
           (select * from positions order by driver, date_hour) a
           , (SELECT @olddriver := '') b,(SELECT @range:=0) c,(SELECT @oldstatus:=0) d
         ) e
      ) f
      GROUP by range_1
      ORDER by driver,date_hour;
```

The result is

```
driver  date_hour               status
bar     2019-10-01 00:15:00     1
bar     2019-10-01 00:31:40     0
bar     2019-10-01 00:31:50     1
bar     2019-10-01 00:48:20     0
bar     2019-10-01 00:48:30     1
bar     2019-10-01 01:05:00     0
bar     2019-10-01 01:05:10     1
bar     2019-10-01 01:21:40     0
foo     2019-10-01 00:00:00     1
foo     2019-10-01 00:16:40     0
foo     2019-10-01 00:16:50     1
foo     2019-10-01 00:33:20     0
foo     2019-10-01 00:33:30     1
foo     2019-10-01 00:50:00     0
foo     2019-10-01 00:50:10     1
foo     2019-10-01 01:06:40     0
```

Can you see at
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=53de8c0510368adf691efe91e0a2a15f

What i did is, I added a range Column, which number represents the actual range. I give every time the staus or driver changes a new rangenumber
After that i group all by this new range.